# Pick camera roll not working in ionic/cordova in iOs nothing happens

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Nothing happens when I call the getPicture function with: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY.
Hower it does work in Android just not iOs and also this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA does work in iOs.

```
private cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
};

public async changeProfilePicture() {
  const sheet = await this.actionSheet.create({
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Camera',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture();
      },
    },
      {
        text: 'Foto album',
        handler: () => {
          this.choosePicture();
        },
      }
      , {
        text: 'Annuleren',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          sheet.dismiss();
        },
      }],
  });

  sheet.present();
}

private async takePicture() {
  try {
    const image = await this.camera.getPicture({
      ...this.cameraOptions,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    });

    this.userService.editProfilePicture(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    this.handleImageError(err);
  }
}

private async choosePicture() {
  try {

    const image = await this.camera.getPicture({
      ...this.cameraOptions,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    });

    this.userService.editProfilePicture(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    this.handleImageError(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS requires permissions to be configured when accessing certain native features. In your case, you need to set the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key in the `Info.plist` file of your app. You can manually edit this file within the xcode project, but it's better to place this in the `config.xml` of your ionic project :

```
<config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
 <string>The app needs access to your library to...</string>
</config-file>
```

Comment: NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is already in the Info.plist file. However I don't see the Photos access toggle in the app settings. I can also see "Photo Library Usage description" set in xcode info tab. What am I doing wrong? I am using capacitor btw.

Comment: I can see the Photo library toggle access and it's enabled in both iPhone and iPad. But it only works in iPhone do you know why?